# How to remove the footer space in android device

Tags: android, css, media-queries

here is the website link which one i have created last week using css3 media query. http://www.i-nsp.com/index.html  This is working fine in desktop and tablet device. But when i am checking in android phone, in the footer area i am getting few extra white space. So any idea how to solve that problem.

thanks,
naresh kumar.

Comment: i think you are using webview for showing this website..right ?

Comment: i am using normal browser. i mean Google chrome.

Comment: i mean you using android phone and open this website so, in any application you open this website or in normal browser opened the website ?

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of your body, you have the following html:

```
<img border="0" src="http://visit1.geo.vip.in2.yahoo.com/visit.gif?&amp;r=http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/12969053/extra-space-after-the-footer-in-android-device&amp;b=Netscape%205.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64%29%20AppleWebKit/537.4%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome/22.0.1229.94%20Safari/537.4&amp;s=1680x1050&amp;o=Win32&amp;c=32&amp;j=true&amp;v=1.2">
```

It causes the space at the bottom.

Remove it, reposition it, or perhaps try to set display:none on it.